# PM2 deploy folder structure - how to use / configure

Tags: node.js, deployment, pm2

I'm deploying a node application using `PM2` and `nvm` as [described in the pm2 documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/). I observe the resulting folder structure, and I'm questionning myself about why it is as it is, and if there is some way to configure it.

My `ecosystem.config.js` just contains the minimun information to connect to git (bitbucket) and check out the project, that's why I think it's not worth to put it here.

This is the folder structure I obtain running `pm2 deploy production setup`:

```
source/
       .git    // git root
       *.*     // all checked out projet files
shared/
       pids/   // empty folder, pids are in ~/.pm2/pids
       logs/   // empty folder, logs are in ~/.pm2/logs
current/       // symlink to /source
.deploys       // git commit ids
```

My questions are:

- What is `/current` for ? navigating directly to `/source` will give the same result. In a capistrano deployment, where I have several releases checked out, having a symlink makes sense, since it allows to rollback instantly, but here I don't see how it could be useful.
- What if I would only keep a subfolder of `/source` in the webroot ? Is there a way to configure this ? Maybe I'm still too much thinking in 'Apache mode', and there is no need for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This github issue very well describes my problem (and others) ;
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2-deploy/issues/27#issue-49186558

The answer to my question is simpler that I hoped:

- the symlink of the  `current/` folder misses its purpose.
- there is no way to configure `pm2 deploy` in a more detailed way.